# Make a feature branch the new development

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

A feature branch is now too far away from  the original development branch to merge back changes. I would rather take this branch as new base for further development.

What is the best method to use this branch as new development branch? As there is no other developer involved there should not be any conflicts.

Comment: Just... start using that branch, instead of the one you used previously. If you want to delete the old "dev" and rename the new one, you can look up how to delete and rename branches in git, but the names are really just conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete your existing **development** branch and create a new development branch from your **feature** branch and start using it as a development branch.

Follow the below command one by one and you will get your new development branch the same as the existing feature branch.

```
git checkout <feature_branch_name>
git branch -D <development_branch_name> // will delete development branch from local
git push origin :<development_branch_name> // will delete development branch from remote
git checkout -b <new_development_branch_name>
git push origin <new_development_branch_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought there is another method without deleting the old one but this will do as well.